# como eu posso fazer para retornar uma consulta agrupando pelo o nome da tabela utilizando pdo, php e mysql?

Tags: php

como eu posso fazer para retornar uma consulta agrupando pelo o nome da tabela utilizando pdo, php e mysql ?

po exemplo eu quero fazer uma consulta e retornar um json igual a esse aqui,utilizando pdo, tem como?

```
{
    "nome da tabela ": [{
        "nome da coluna": "225",
        "nome da coluna": "16",

    }],
    "outra tabela": [{
        "nome da coluna": "226",
        "nome da coluna": "16",
        "nome da coluna": "95",

    }, {
        "nome da coluna": "226",
        "nome da coluna": "16",
        "nome da coluna": "99",

    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB_Tests', 'asdfds', 'dsad');

$tabelas = array('users', 'posts'); // aqui coloca as tabelas que quer
$dados = array();
foreach($tabelas as $table) {
    $dados[$table] = array();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' .$table;
    $data = $db->prepare($sql);
    $data->execute();
    foreach($data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $collumn => $value) {
        $dados[$table][$collumn] = $value;
    }
}
$jsonData = json_encode($dados);
```

Na variável `$tabelas` vai definir as tabelas que quer

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi o numero da coluna

> "nome da coluna": "226",

Mas você pode fazer uma consula na [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) com o `CAST (AS JSON)`

```
SELECT table_name, CAST(
    ( SELECT ISC.COLUMN_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as ISC
      WHERE ISC.table_name = IST.table_name)
 AS JSON) as json_colunas
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as IST
  WHERE IST.table_schema = 'db_name'
```